# Putting gym equipment in a room where one prays?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sport-athletics

Can one put gym equipment in a room where he prays (if he has no other place to put it)?

Would it desecrate the place where one prays and negatively affect his prayers?

Comment: What do you mean negatively affect his prayers. Subjectivity? Or objectively (not sure how)?

Comment: I don't understand "he has no other place to put it". Presumably he can throw it out, or pray in a different room. If you really mean he has no other place to put it than where he prays (it's impossible), then of course he can put in a room where he prays: he has no choice. I really don't understand this question.

Comment: Would the gym equipment distract you at all?

Comment: @robev I suppose it would make the place where he prays less holy

Comment: @ilja It wouldn't distract, I'm afraid it would make the place where he prays less holy

Comment: As long as one did not explicitly dedicate a room to be a Beit Knesset and/or brought a Torah scroll, it has no sanctity on its own. One can daven in the kitchen or the balcony - practically anywhere in the house. Mere davening in a room does not turn it automatically into a shul. In other words: you're davening in a basement and not working out in a Beit Knesset.

Comment: @AlBerko Even if it's a place which one has specifically chosen to pray at every time?

Comment: @AlBerko you should turn your comment into answer with sources I guess)